# Integration of $-\int_{\pi/2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2x)}{x^2\cdot e^x}\,dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

[How to calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2e^x}dx$ (it beats Maxima)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4031737/how-to-calculate-int-0-infty-frac1-cosxx2exdx-it-beats-maxima?noredirect=1#comment8324686_4031764)

I have a similar integral as the one above, but the difference is that the bottom limit is $\frac\pi2$ instead of $0$

$$I = -\int_{\pi/2}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{x^2\cdot e^x}\,dx$$

The problem is if i use DUIS (AKA Feynmann Trick) twice **just exactly like in the second answer** (i hope this clear out what i did without posting my steps) i would get:

$$I''(t) = \frac{e^{-\pi/2}}{t^2+1}\left(\sin\frac{\pi t}2+t\cos\frac{\pi t}2\right)$$

instead of $\dfrac{t}{t^2+1}$ (so i kind of getting back to where i started before doing the trick).

Im stuck, is there any other way to do this without using Taylor Series and DUIS ?

if it's still not clear of what i did take a look at picture below.

[image: Step]

[image: Step]

Comment: Oh sweet Jesus. A black background image on a white background with bright blue foreground is really rough on the eyes.

Comment: FWIW, a reduction formula is probably a little simpler for evaluating that penultimate integral rather than hopping to complex numbers. There's a little less bookkeeping. That said, I think you're out of luck here. One thing that the other solution had over yours is that the integral started at $0$ which normalized a lot of the behavior. With your starting point shifted, the method fails a bit.

Comment: You end up with exponential integrals as a result of your shifted lower endpoint.

Comment: I tried shifting to the left by $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ too, but i think it just slightly got worse.

Comment: If you try shifting your lower limit to $0$, you'll get an integral that is not well-defined as the singularity at the origin is non-integrable.

Answer (score 2):

There is an antiderivative (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSin%5B2x%5D%2Fx%5E2%2FExp%5Bx%5D%2Cx%5D). So
$$I=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{x^2\, e^x}\;dx$$
$$I=-\pi -\frac 12 \Bigg[(2-i) \text{Ei}\left(\left(-\frac{1}{2}-i\right) \pi \right)+(2+i)
   \text{Ei}\left(\left(-\frac{1}{2}+i\right) \pi \right) \Bigg]$$

Then the result which numerically is
$$-0.020032230502695703874141776260168\cdots$$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

**Edit**

Without the help of Wolfram Alpha, consider
$$J=\int\dfrac{\cos(2x)+i\sin(2x)}{x^2\, e^x}\;dx=\int\dfrac{e^{2ix}}{x^2\, e^x}\;dx=\int \frac{e^{(-1+2 i) x}}{x^2}\,dx$$ $$J=(1-2i)\int \frac{e^{-y}}{y^2}\,dy=-(1-2i)\Big[\text{Ei}(-y)+\frac{e^{-y}}{y}\Big]$$

Comment: If you've used $Ei$ then that means you've used Taylor series, i want to know whether it can be done without Taylor Series and only by DUIS 
(Beside the result is positive). 
But i think because of the shifted lower bound it might not be possible without Taylor Series, hm....

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: @JamboRambo you can get the answer easily by noting that $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ without directly referencing the Taylor series. However this is trivial based on the definition of $\operatorname{Ei}$, so do with that what you will.

Comment: Claude, I think you have a typo in your prompt, in theory you should either change your upper bound of integration or change $I(\frac{\pi}{2})$ to something else. Minor typo, but might be confusing for others. I don't want to edit it since I'm not sure which you truly had in mind.

Comment: @CameronWilliams. I did not care about the minus sign in the question.

Comment: Isn't $I(\pi/2)=0$? In that case you intrgrate over an interval of length zero.

Comment: @Gary hit my point home a bit better. There's an inconsistency somewhere.

Comment: @Gary. Double checked at https://www.integral-calculator.com/# . This is Maxima. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici In the definition of $I(t)$ you integrate from $\pi/2$ to $t$. So $I(\pi/2)$ means you integrate on an interval of length zero, i.e., the integral must be zero. I am talking about the second line of your answer.

Comment: @Gary. I apologize ! Wrong notations ! I shall edit.